# neo4j Alternative path

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm doing a simple routing software, and the classical need to achieve a "good product" is offering to the customer different path.

I'm using cypher, but as far as I know, it is not achievable.. I can only find "allShortestPath" of my graph and not "almost shortest".

My idea was executing multiple time dijkstra adding some weight on the first of the previous path, so it "probably" will look at another path. The problem is that I don't know how to let cypher evaluate temporary weghts on my graph.

I could even think to create a custom plugin using neo4j's java api, and I could use dijkstra algo directly with weight evaluator, but then I don't think I could get all possible paths, but only one

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 1):

What about getting the length of the shortest path and than ask neo4j for a path of that length+1.

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
START n1=node(167), n2=node(169) MATCH p = (n1)-[*..3]-(n2) WHERE length(p) = length(shortestPath((n1)-[]-(n2)))+1 RETURN p
```

You'd probably want to limit the maximum path length.

Comment: START n1=node:users (name = "n1"), n2=node:users (name = "n13")
MATCH p = (n1)-[*length(shortestPath((n1)-[*]-(n2))) + 1]-(n2)
RETURN p
I can't figure out the problem. Response:
Invalid input 'l': expected whitespace, RangeLiteral, a property map or ']' (line 2, column 18)
"MATCH p = (n1)-[*length(shortestPath((n1)-[*]-(n2))) + 1]-(n2)"
                  ^

Comment: It appears you can't use a variable in as path length.

Comment: it seems i can't even use a variable.. I have just started with neo4j, and tried with match l = length(shortest(....)) but I didn't succeed, do you have any example how to use a variable?

Comment: Try the (new) example in the answer. It is at least syntactically correct and I think does what you want @rodi

Comment: Did you limit the path length to something reasonable. I changed the example again and have tested it on the Matrix sample graph. It now does exactly what you want.

Comment: @commesan we tried your tip (not your chyper) but in a graph with 10 million of nodes and 50 million of relationships we had really really really poor perfomances in getting the path between 2 far nodes....may you tell me your graph dimensions? did u test on on a great grpah?

Comment: The sample graph is 150 nodes or so. This doesn't perform well on large graphs as it will compute all paths and then filter. Ideally you 'd be able to pass the max length as a path variable so it wouldn't traverse all possible paths. But cypher doesn't support that. @AngeloImmediata

Answer (score 0):

There is work in progress for allowing dijkstra to return more than one path, currently it returns all shortest paths.

```
START n1=node(167), n2=node(169) 
MATCH p=shortestPath((n1)-[]-(n2))
WITH n1,n2,length(p)+1 as almost_shortest
MATCH p = (n1)-[*..3]-(n2) 
WHERE length(p) = almost_shortest 
RETURN p
```

I still you're best using a modified dijkstra or other path-finding algorithm that provides you with the number of paths.

With the traversal-description or bidirectional-traversal-description and custom PathEvaluators / PathExpander you can build whatever you want.